# less: how to skip N files

Tags: less

From the `less` man page:

```
:n     Examine the next file (from the list of files given in the command line).  If a number N
       is specified, the N-th next file is examined.
```

How this number N can be specified? When I type `:n` it goes immediately the the next file, not waiting even for an `ENTER`.

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The number must be entered before the command; to skip two files, press <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. (`less` often behaves the same way as `vi`; in fact its manual says “Commands are based on both `more` and `vi`.”)